# Raphael animation

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I am new to Raphael and am trying to do something very simple, but failing miserably.

I am trying to replicate the animation at [this link](http://www.trottercashion.com/2010/04/22/i-heart-raphael.html) This is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src=" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="draw-here-raphael" style="height: 200px; width: 400px; background: #666;">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//all your javascript goes here

var r = new Raphael("draw-here-raphael", 400, 200),

    // Store where the box is
    position = 'left',

    // Make our pink rectangle
    rect = r.rect(20, 20, 50, 50).attr({"fill": "#fbb"});

// Note JQuery is adding the mouseover. SVG == html nodes
$(rect.node).mouseover(function () {
  if (position === 'left') {
    rect.animate({x: 300, y: 100}, 400, "<>");
    position = 'right';
  } else {
    rect.animate({x: 20, y: 20 }, 800, "bounce");
    position = 'left';
  }
});
// Make that sucker rotate
setInterval(function () {
  rect.rotate(1);
}, 10);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have downloaded jquery and have it in the same folder as the Raphael.  The code that isn't working is the commented code talking about jquery adding the mouseover.  When I add that code the rectangle doesn't rotate anymore.  It is just stationary.  If someone can please help me with this animation I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see something wrong here:  <script src=" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your code:

```
<script src=" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

Change it to:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

That should correct your problem with jQuery.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Thank you.  Now the animation is working, but it is not going to the bottom right of the page.  It will go off to the left or the bottom and disappear.  Any thoughts?